# Hacer scroll con un recyclerViev dentro

Tags: android, recyclerview

Estoy realizando una aplicacion con un sistema de comentarios y calificaciones
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el xml del layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
               android:id="@+id/evento_name"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@color/azullEvento"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
               android:textSize="30sp" />

            <WebView
               android:id="@+id/descricion_larga"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:background="@color/grisEvento"
               android:gravity="top">

            </WebView>

            <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/social_section"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="130dp"
               android:gravity="bottom"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:visibility="visible">

                <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RatingBar
                       android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                       android:numStars="5" />

                    <Button
                       android:id="@+id/calificar"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:text="@string/btn_calificar" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout

                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                       android:id="@+id/comentario"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:ems="10"
                       android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                       android:labelFor="@id/comentario" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                       android:id="@+id/lista_comentarios"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

El sistema funciona solo que el scroll solo se realiza en la recyclerView y no lo hace con toda la pantalla

Comment: Debes escribir tu layout es decir el archivo xml de tu pagina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa lo siguiente

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:fillViewport="false">

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
               android:id="@+id/evento_name"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@color/azullEvento"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
               android:textSize="30sp" />

            <WebView
               android:id="@+id/descricion_larga"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:background="@color/grisEvento"
               android:gravity="top">

            </WebView>

            <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/social_section"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="130dp"
               android:gravity="bottom"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:visibility="visible">

                <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RatingBar
                       android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                       android:numStars="5" />

                    <Button
                       android:id="@+id/calificar"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:text="@string/btn_calificar" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout

                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                       android:id="@+id/comentario"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:ems="10"
                       android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                       android:labelFor="@id/comentario" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                       android:id="@+id/lista_comentarios"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout> 
</ScrollView>
```